# A leading question mark in oracle using datastage to import from text to oracle?

Tags: oracle, import, oracle11g, datastage

The question mark "?" appears only in the front of the first field of the first row to insert.
For once, I changed the ftp upload file type to text/ascii (rather than binary) and it seemed resolve the problem. But later it came back.
The server OS is aix5.3.
DataStage is 7.5x2.
Oracle is 11g.

I used ue to save the file to utf-8, using unix end mark.
Has anyone got this thing before?

Answer (score 1):

The question mark itself doesn't mean much as it could be only a "mask" for some special character which is not recognized by the database. You didn't provide any details about your environment, so my opinions here are only a guess. I hope it can give you a little of a light.

How is the text file created? If it's a file created in a windows environment you're very likely to have character like this due brake lines {CR}{LF} characters.

What is the datatype for the oracle table?
Char datatype will "fill" every position according to the size of the field, I'd recommend to use varchar instead on this case.

If it's not the case, I would edit the file in Hex mode and check for the Ascii code for this specific character then use a TRIM (if parallel) or Convert(if server) to replace the character.

The convert function would be something like this:

Convert(Char([ascii_char_number]),'',[your_string])

Alternatively you can use the Trim function if your job is a parallel job

Trim([your_string],[ascii_char_number],'L')

The option "L" will remove all leading characters. You might need to adapt this function to suit your needs. If you're not familiar with the TRIM function you can find more details at the datastage online documentation.

The only warning I'd give when doing this, is that you'll be deleting data from your original source of data, so make sure you're not deleting any valid information when manipulating a file like this as this is not a very recommended practice between the ETL gurus out there.

Any questions, give me a shout. Happy to help if I can.

Cheers

Comment: Thanks. As I remember, the resolution was change the type of the file to "utf-8 no bom"

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue where unprintable characters were being displayed as '?' and datastage was throwing a warning when processing these records. It was ok for me to not display those unprintable characters, so I used the function ICONV which converts those characters into printable ones. There are multiple options, I chose the one which will convert them to '.' which worked for me. More details are available in the IBM pages below:

https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZJPZ_11.3.0/com.ibm.swg.im.iis.ds.parjob.dev.doc/topics/r_deeref_String_Functions.html

http://docs.intersystems.com/ens201317/csp/docbook/DocBook.UI.Page.cls?KEY=RVBS_foconv

The conversion I used:
ICONV(column_name,"MCP")